# Can't set fill color to CGRect/path quartz

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

I want to make and fill a rectangle with color. But my code doesnt work (no rectangle appears). Please tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 84, 84, 84, 1);
firstTower = CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, 200);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

if (_touchHasBegun)
{
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 34, 102, 1);                    
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 135, 206, 250, 0.25);
    rectangle = CGRectMake(1, 1, 500, 500);
    CGContextAddArc(context, pointWhereUserClickedX, pointWhereUserClickedY, 50, 0, 2*3.14159265359, YES);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);


}
```

}

If statement is a circle.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I actually solved this problem by remove the first CGCOntextDrawPath line. But please look at the updated question with a new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rectangle doesn't appear because you're not adding it to the context. You've created a `CGRect` and assigned it to the `firstTower` variable, but you never tell the context about it.

You probably want to add

```
CGContextAddRect(context, firstTower);
```

after assigning to `firstTower`.

Similarly you're not adding the `rectangle` value on the second draw.